# Custom launcher in gnome unable to launch XAMPP control panel

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, xampp

I was following [this tutorial](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410) for setting up xampp, but adding the xampp control panel to the Gnome application launcher doesn't seem to work. Here's the content of my `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start/Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=gksudo "python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py"
Icon[en_CA]=/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/devices/network-wired.svg
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Name[en_CA]=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment[en_CA]=Start/Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/devices/network-wired.svg
```

Then I tried changing the `Exec` line for:

```
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

Now, it does add it to the menu, but I'm then unable to launch it; clicking on it doesn't do anything. Also, I'm able to add it with Alacarte menu, but that doesn't change anything (excepted that I have this application twice in my menu).  Note that the same command does work with CLI.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Was there something implied by the aforementioned tutorial that I missed?

My setting: **Ubuntu 16.04.2** with Gnome Shell 3.18.5 and **Python 2.7.12/3.5.2** .

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The site's purpose is a knowledge base of solutions that allows other people with a similar problem to share the solutions.  Your question references the tutorial you followed.  If that link becomes unavailable, the question will be hard for future readers to understand.  Can you include enough of the essential information within the question so it is more self-contained?  (It can be just the gist of the procedure plus any specifics needed to understand the question.  Keep the link for attribution and reference.)  Thanks.

Comment: When you say you're unable to launch it, do you mean the menu entry is unresponsive?  What exactly happens?

Comment: Sorry, I don't live in an english speaking country nor I'm used to sysadmin speech, so yes I guess "menu entry is unresponsive" is the right description for what's happening: I have the non-icon in my menu, but clicking on it doesn't do anything. Also I'm able to add it with Alacarte menu, but that doesn't change anything (excepted that I have this application twice in my menu).